# Script needs to move one file to another directory; can't move it without its parent directory tree

Tags: shell-script, shell, ubuntu, mv

In a bash script, I have:

```
TEMPPATH="/tmp/directory"

BACKUPPATH="/backup/path"
```

I'm trying to move one file using:

```
mv $TEMPPATH/file $BACKUPPATH/file
```

I want to move the file from `/tmp/directory/file` to `/backup/path/file`, but instead it ends up in `/backup/path/tmp/directory/file`. I've tried adding and removing trailing slashes from the destination, and excluding the filename from the destination (just using the destination directory). I've searched and find a lot of methods for moving lots of files in a directory, but I only want to move one.

========

EDIT: here is the script section that causes the problem. It's part of a script that backs up WordPress folders and databases. Note: if you are wondering why I'm not just zipping the files directly to the backup location, it's because I'm writing to Keybase. If you haven't used Keybase, since i/o to and from it is so slow, my goal was to zip files locally then move the file after zipping is complete.

```
#back up the WordPress folder and move over to backup location
echo Compressing site files
zip -r --quiet $TEMPPATH/$DATEFORM-$SITE.wp-content.zip .
echo Moving site zip file to Keybase
#mv $TEMPPATH/$DATEFORM-$SITE.wp-content.zip $BACKUPPATH/$SITE/$DATEFORM-$SITE.wp-content.zip
# ---------> this mv command works as expected:
mv $TEMPPATH/$DATEFORM-$SITE.wp-content.zip $BACKUPPATH/$SITE

#back up the WordPress database, compress, move to backup location and clean up
echo Exporting database
/usr/local/bin/wp db export $TEMPPATH/$DATEFORM-$SITE.sql --all-tablespaces --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false --allow-root --skip-themes --skip-plugins
echo Compressing database
zip --quiet $TEMPPATH/$DATEFORM-$SITE.sql.zip $TEMPPATH/$DATEFORM-$SITE.sql
# ---------> this is the way the script was originally written -- maybe this cat method was used to prevent the same problem I am having?
# cat $TEMPPATH/$DATEFORM-$SITE.sql | zip > $TEMPPATH/$DATEFORM-$SITE.sql.zip
echo Moving sql zip file to Keybase
# ---------> this is the mv command that results in the directory tree being copied over to the destination
mv $TEMPPATH/$DATEFORM-$SITE.sql.zip $BACKUPPATH/$SITE
echo Removing tmp file
rm $TEMPPATH/$DATEFORM-$SITE.sql
```

Comment: Welcome!  What you have works for me.  Are you sure that you didn't misspell on of the variables in your script?  Do any of your paths contain spaces?

Comment: What's the output of `type mv`?

Comment: @jimmij, ```type mv``` returns ``mv is /bin/mv``

Comment: 1. It is a good idea to double-quote the variables, for example `"$DATEFORM"`; 2. Furthermore, it is a good idea to use curly brackets to mark the end of a variable, when it is directly followed by some character (except whitespace) or another variable, for example  `"${DATEFORM}-${SITE}.sql.zip"

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example and it works as expected - see output below.
What `mv` version do you use and on what system? And a piece of advice, to avoid any special characters (e.g. names with spaces) doing unexpected things I recommend quoting your variables and you can drop file name from the target: `mv "$TEMPPATH/file" "$BACKUPPATH/"`.

Example from the question:

```
$ tree /tmp/directory
/tmp/directory
└── file

0 directories, 1 file
$ tree /backup
/backup
└── path

1 directory, 0 files
$ TEMPPATH="/tmp/directory"
$ BACKUPPATH="/backup/path"
$ mv $TEMPPATH/file $BACKUPPATH/file
$ tree /tmp/directory
/tmp/directory

0 directories, 0 files
$ tree /backup
/backup
└── path
    └── file

1 directory, 1 file
```

Still cannot reproduce:

```
$ tree /tmp/test /backup/
/tmp/test
└── some-example.sql
/backup/
└── path

1 directory, 1 file
$ TEMPPATH=/tmp/test
$ DATEFORM=some
$ SITE=example
$ BACKUPPATH=/backup/path
$ zip --quiet $TEMPPATH/$DATEFORM-$SITE.sql.zip $TEMPPATH/$DATEFORM-$SITE.sql
$ mv $TEMPPATH/$DATEFORM-$SITE.sql.zip $BACKUPPATH/$SITE
$ tree /tmp/test /backup/
/tmp/test
└── some-example.sql
/backup/
└── path
    └── example

1 directory, 2 files
```

Comment: How strange. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I did try dropping the filename from the target as suggested.

Comment: I added the actual script above in case that helps.

Comment: I think it isn't fault of the `mv` command - there must be something changing the variable used to specify the target. Maybe try printing the command (`echo mv $TEMPPATH/$DATEFORM-$SITE.sql.zip $BACKUPPATH/$SITE`) or related variables (or log to a file `echo "$BACKUPPATH/$SITE" >> /tmp/log`) every few lines.

Comment: I made some changes as recommended and now I am getting the file to move properly, though the filename when extracted is simply "-". Perhaps there is something wrong with the way the variable is stored. Thanks everyone for your input. Learned lots.